# Wrong average bandwidth stats in arm?

Tags: bandwidth, nyx, stats

See screenshot below. Arm seems to calculate a wrong average: "avg: 2.3 MB/sec".
I haven't been close to 2.3 MegaByte/sec; not even as peek.

That's my relay:
https://atlas.torproject.org/#details/583F17298E905D1D1BCF8EB49DAEE5939B51FD70

Note that I have set "features.graph.bw.transferInBytes true" in the armrc.
When I set it back to "features.graph.bw.transferInBytes false", which is default, all values, including the high average, go up by factor eight. So no bit/byte confusion as far as I can see.

Anybody experiencing the same?

What time period is arm using for averaging by the way?

[image: arm]

Comment: You are not alone, my relay says 430Mb/s.. but if I "clean" the history, the avg. speed change..

Answer (score 0):

As to measured bandwidth, which I understand = consensus weight
it is wrong by a factor of 1000

unit in kB means MB